# How do I keep this image in the floated div centered vertically when the text wraps?

Tags: css

I've done some research to figure out how to keep the text aligned with the red box (which will be replaced with an icon) after it wraps.

But now because of the float, the icon is raised to the top of the container `<td>`. Unfortunately now I'm stuck with how to center the `div.imgwrap` vertically within its parent, after the link wraps to two lines.

Is it possible to do this just with CSS, without having to modify the HTML? The obvious solution is to just add an extra column for the icons, but that would take a lot more work.

http://jsfiddle.net/fzvy5oca/

```
<table>
  <tr class="">
    <td>
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/H2Vulqm.png" alt="[   ]" width="16" height="16">
      </div>

        <a href="test">test really long name....</a>

    </td>
    <td>smaller column</td>
    <td>small column</td>
    <td>medium size column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table,
tr,
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.125rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.imgwrap {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  float: left;
}

.imgwrap + a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.imgwrap img {
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: try this CSS `td{position: relative;}` and `.imgwrap{position: absolute;
    top: 25px;}`

Comment: I want it to be centered regardless the height of the parent div. Absolute positioning won't keep it centered if the height changes.

Comment: Absolute positioning won't keep it centered if the height changes : Not always. you can transform it to keep alwasy at the center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what u want?
http://jsfiddle.net/fzvy5oca/22/

**Css**

```
td {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.125rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.imgwrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -8px; /* half of #imgwrap's height */

  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I have a question - how come if I don't have a relative position on the td, it doesn't work? Shouldn't that just change the position of the td itself?

Comment: if you have absolute on children element, you need to define a father element to be relatived. In your question, .imgwrap wants to be on the 50% vertical of td, so the father element for .imgwrap is td. Besides, the x/y-axis of .imgwrap is on left top, you need to push half height back then .imgwrap will be completely center. More imformation: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.125rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*Added*/
  position: relative;
}

.imgwrap {
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*display: inline-block; removed */
  margin-right: 8px;
  /*float: left; removed */
  /*Added*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.imgwrap + a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.imgwrap img {
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="">
    <td>
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/H2Vulqm.png" alt="[   ]" width="16" height="16">
      </div>
      
        <a href="test">test really long name.test really long name.test really long name.test really long name.test really long name.test really long name.test really long name.test really long name....</a>

    </td>
    <td>smaller column</td>
    <td>small column</td>
    <td>medium size column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.imgwrap {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
  <table>
  <tr class="">
    <td>
      <div class="imgwrap">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/H2Vulqm.png" alt="[   ]" width="16" height="16">
        <a href="test">test really long name....</a>
      </div>

    </td>
    <td>smaller column</td>
    <td>small column</td>
    <td>medium size column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```